# The code "new Array(count + 1).join(string)" What does it mean? How does it work?

Tags: javascript, html, function

i have a code that prints
***aaaa
Error in string or count.
Error in string or count.
Error in string or count.***

```
function repeat_string(string, count) 
  {
    if ((string == null) || (count < 0) || (count === Infinity) || (count == null))
      {
        return('Error in string or count.');
      }
        // Floor count.
    return new Array(count + 1).join(string);
  }

console.log(repeat_string('a', 4));
console.log(repeat_string('a'));
console.log(repeat_string('a', -2));
console.log(repeat_string('a', Infinity));
```

***But I cannot understand why there are a 4 times i.e what does  return new Array(count + 1).join(string);*** does??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// creates a new array of the specified length,
// filled with undefined
const arr = new Array(3);

// [undefined, undefined, undefined]

// join the elements of the array, using ‘x’ to connect them:
arr.join(‘x’);

// undefined + ‘x’ + undefined + ‘x’ + undefined
// ‘xx’
```

Answer (score 0):

## Array constructor

[Array() constructor - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array)

Syntax

> new Array(arrayLength)

> arrayLength
> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 2^32-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values). If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown

`new Array(4)` is same empty array `[,,,,]`.

## join

[Array.prototype.join() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#:%7E:text=The%20join()%20method%20creates,returned%20without%20using%20the%20separator.)

> The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string.

---

### Addendum in response to comments

> so will any other no greater than 232 will give me range error??

Sorry. Because the powers was expressed in HTML, I didn't copy and paste the powers well. I fix 232 to 2^32.

It's not 232 that goes over the array, as @ray hatfield commented.

You can confirm the error by doing the following:

```
new Array(Infinity)
```

VM67:1 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length
at :1:1

and

```
new Array(2**32)
```

VM337:1 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length
at :1:1

And the following code will not produce an error.

```
new Array(2**32-1)
```

Comment: so will any other no  greater than 232 will give me range error??

Comment: That’s `2^32-1`, (2 to the 32nd, minus 1), not 232: `4,294,967,295`

Comment: @AnurupMondal Sorry. I mistake copy paste. I edit myanswer.

Answer (score 0):

`new Array(count + 1)` gives you an empty array with count + 1 length.

`array.join(string)` concatenates the contents of the array with the `string` in between each element.

In your case, `new Array(count + 1).join(string)` returns aaaa as there are 5 empty spaces, joined with one 'a' in between each one.